# f.className.indexOf is not a function - highlighter.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ionic-framework

I am building an app with `ionic` and in the console I am getting the following error with `highlighter.js` in `chrome`:

[image: Screenshot of the console showing the error]

It is not a big issue, since the app is working correctly but I would like to understand why I am getting such error. I did some searches, but I could not find any proper solution to this problem. Do you have an idea on what is the cause of this issue?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found what the issue is: it is connected with a chrome extension called [`multi-highlight`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multi-highlight/pfgfgjlejbbpfmcfjhdmikihihddeeji) and by re-installing it I have solved the problem.